# swift, How to add 4 buttons to a ImageVIew

Tags: swift, uikit

can somebody help me, how to set a proper way to obtain an image view with 4 buttons right on the every angle of this view!

```
private func createResisedButtons() {
    for index in 0..<4 {
        
        let button = UIButton()
        
        if index == 0 {
//                button.bounds = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.minX, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            
        } else if index == 1 {

        } else if index == 2 {
//                button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: imageView.frame.maxY, width: 30, height: 30)
            

        } else if index == 3 {

        }
        
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .allTouchEvents)
        imageView.addSubview(button)

        buttonsArray.append(button)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to do it. You can find quite a lot of useful information about `bounds` / `frame` properties and even Auto Layout just by searching for it on Google. Since you were trying to set the buttons `bounds`, you should take a look at those:

1. [Frame - Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame)
2. [Bounds - Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds)

I built a small project setting their `frame` instead. In the code down below, you get a `UIButton` placed at each angle of the `UIImageView`. Just keep in mind that `frame` stands for the view location and size **in its superview's coordinate system**. You can import it and play with it to better undestand what is happening and why.

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_HERE")
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private lazy var button1: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var button2: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var button3: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var button4: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.addSubview(button1)
        imageView.addSubview(button2)
        imageView.addSubview(button3)
        imageView.addSubview(button4)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: view.frame.size.width-40, height: view.frame.size.height/2-40)
        button1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.width-30, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        button3.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: imageView.frame.height-30, width: 30, height: 30)
        button4.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.width-30, y: imageView.frame.height-30, width: 30, height: 30)
    }

    @objc private func buttonTapped() {
        print("Button tapped")
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: as Duncan C rightfully pointed out, modern versions of iOS tend to prefer Auto Layout over setting frames programmatically. Using Auto Layout, you have to take special steps to prevent Auto Layout constraints from moving your views around in situations like device rotation. (e.g. leaving `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` ([see Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)) set to `true`.)

You can read more about Auto Layout [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Good answer overall, but a few suggestions: Explain that modern versions of iOS tend to use AutoLayout, and you have to take special steps to prevent AutoLayout constraints from moving your views around in situations like device rotation. (e.g. leaving `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`  set to true.) Also, since you went to the trouble of writing a full sample app, why not upload it to a free Github account and sharing it in your answer.

Comment: @DuncanC you have a point, I've edited my answer according to your statement. :) Tbf I wasn't really aware that Auto Layout is more used nowadays, good to know, I'm still learning Swift myself and do it for a hobby. I've always found much more intuitive to work with frames programmatically. I might set up a new Github account for the purpose tomorrow.